# Unable to use the ribbon "Download a Copy" when multiple documents are selected

Tags: document-library, ribbon, download

Several users reported that the ribbon button gets grayed out as soon as they select multiple documents to download from a document library.

The feature works fine if you select a single document and gets disabled as soon as you select a second one.

Is it a normal behavior? or did we miss something while configuring the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior as SharePoint does not support a "bulk" style download of multiple files.  If you need to do that it would be better to just open Explorer View and copy the files that way.